# LINQ join statement issues

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with a LINQ statement.

I have 3 tables: `Examinations`, `ExaminationProtocols` and `SampleTests`.

Until now I have used this statement as I needed only the information only of the first two tables.

```
var baseQuery = from e in context.Examinations
                join ep in context.ExaminationProtocols
                on e.ID equals ep.ExaminationID into er
                from r in er.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { E = e, EP = r };
```

But now I need to get the `ExaminationProtocols` that have at least 1 `SampleTest` with a field `acccurate = true`.

The foreign key between the `SampleTest` and `ExaminationProtocols` is

```
EP.ID equal ST.examinationProtocolID
```

I tried to join the third table inside the statement but doesn't seem to get the result I desire.

If anyone can give me a tip I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you the required result?

```
var baseQuery = from e in context.Examinations
                join ep in context.ExaminationProtocols
                    on e.ID equals ep.ExaminationID into er
                from r in er.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join st in context.SampleTests
                    on r.ID equals st.examinationProtocolID
                where st.acccurate
                select new { E = e, EP = r };
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be written like this

```
var baseQuery = from e in Examinations
              join ep in ExaminationProtocols.Where(x => SampleTests.Where(y => y.accurate).Select(z => z.examinationProtocolID).Contains(x.ID))
                  on e.ID equals ep.ExaminationID into er
              from r in er.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { E = e, EP = r };
```